# Sharepoint 2010 update tasks

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, update

I have a single SharePoint 2010 sp2 (14.0.7171.5000) server on which I need to apply an update. I am new to SharePoint so I wanted to check on the best practice steps pre and post update. I plan on backing up the DB beforehand but I wanted to know is this enough? also I believe there is a command that needs to be run after updating but I see mixed content on the web about if it is required or not.

If there is a recommended link to best practices/ steps for applying an update to SP that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, backing up the databases is all you really need to do provided you have a documented process to recreate the farm from scratch as not all settings will be backed up. You can also run a `Backup-SPFarm -ConfigurationOnly` to extract other settings that would not be restored from an upgrade failure.

Install the SharePoint update on all SharePoint servers in the farm. Once complete, run the SharePoint 2010 Configuration Wizard on all servers in the farm.

That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following things.

**Pre:**

- Test the update in lower farm, Apply it and test the updates.
- Backup of Databases
- Backup of your customization (if any i.e. custom changes to web.config , soluions etc)
- Also back up farm configuration.
- Schedule a down time as this process will bring the farm down.

**Post:**

- Install the Update on the server.
- Now run the SharePoint Product and Configuration wizard.
- Test your farm.
- Perform the full backup of databases.

Answer (score 1):

**Before you getting started, you should be aware of the following:**

1. it’s recommended to install the CU that will solve a specific issue in your farm, by checking the improvements and issues that should be fixed before applying the cumulative update.
2. It’s not recommended to install SharePoint update on production environment until tested on dev/test environment.
3. You should also read the prerequisites section on the release page.
4. Performa full backup before starting the update process because you can’t rollback the Cumulative Update Installation.

---

**Patching SharePoint farm consists of 2 main steps:**

- Download and Install the package update.
- Run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard on all sharepoint server within your farm started from the server that hosts the Central Administration.  (in your case, it's standalone server so just perform (Download-Install-Run))

For more details check

- [What’re the prerequisites for installing a new Cumulative update?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/#lnk4)
- [How can you install a new Cumulative update, Service Pack, and PU?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/#lnk5)